# Existence of harmonic maps onto the $n$-sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed smooth Riemannian $n$-manifold with positive scalar curvature (or positive  Ricci curvature) and $(S^n, g_{st})$ be the standard round $n$-sphere.

Whether there exists a non-zero degree harmonic map $f$ from $M^n$ onto $S^n$, $f:M^n\to S^n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example where the answer is 'no' is when $M=\mathbb{RP}^2$ (with, say, the standard metric of Gauss curvature $K\equiv1$, though, in dimension $2$, only the conformal structure on $M$ matters in the definition of harmonic map).

There is no non-constant harmonic map $f:\mathbb{RP}^2\to S^2$ (when $S^2$ given the standard metric with $K\equiv1$).  In particular, there is not one that has nonzero degree.

The reason is that such a map would lift to $\tilde f:S^2\to S^2$ as a non-constant harmonic map, and it is well-known that such a map would have to be either holomorphic or anti-holomorphic when $S^2$ is regarded as $\mathbb{CP}^1$, i.e., the Riemann sphere.  Since $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is $\mathbb{CP}^1=S^2$ divided by the anti-holomorphic involution $[z,w]\to [-\bar w,\bar z]$, it would follow that the holomorphic mapping $\tilde f$ would have to satisfy $\tilde f\bigl([z,w]\bigr) =\tilde f\bigl([-\bar w,\bar z]\bigr)$, which would be impossible unless $\tilde f$ were constant.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have higher-dimensional examples?  Since I need the existence to attack the problem of scalar curvature.   In particular, whether the map $Id: (S^n, g)\to (S^n, g_{st})$ is a harmonic map?  Here $Id$ is the identity map,  $n\geq 5$ and the scalar curvature of $g$ is positive.

Comment: @JialongDeng:  Are you asking for the condition on a metric $g$ on $S^n$ that the identity map $\mathrm{Id}:(S^n,g)\to(S^n,g_{st})$ be harmonic and the scalar curvature be positive?  Since this is an underdetermined system of second order PDE, there are likely to be so many examples that they can't be classified.

Comment: Yes.   Can it be helpful if we add the condition: $|v|_g\geq |v|_{g_{st}}$ for any $v\in TS^n$?

Comment: @JialongDeng:  Actually, that won't be all that helpful.  If a metric $g$ satisfies the stated conditions, then multiplying it by a sufficiently large constant will yield a new metric $g'$ that satisfies this additional inequality as well.